# Why refactor argument of List<Term> to IEnumerable<Term>?

Tags: c#, interface, refactoring, resharper

I have a method that looks like this:

```
    public void UpdateTermInfo(List<Term> termInfoList)
    {
        foreach (Term termInfo in termInfoList)
        {
            UpdateTermInfo(termInfo);
        }
        m_xdoc.Save(FileName.FullName);
    }
```

Resharper advises me to change the method signature to `IEnumerable<Term>` instead of `List<Term>`. What is the benefit of doing this?

Comment: @cherhan kinda the reverse, but I guess the pluses/minuses are the same

Comment: R# 6 has the 'Why is ReSharper suggesting this?' item on the lightbulb menu, which takes you [to JetBrains' explanation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/Parameter+type+can+be+IEnumerable+of+T). Note that R# isn't 'advising' you to do anything, merely pointing out that that parameter *can* be typed as `IEnumerable<>`

Comment: Vote to reopen.  The duplicate question has answers which apply to this question, but the focus is different.  The answers to this question provide more helpful information as a result of the changed focus.

Comment: @Brian Fine, I'll flip flop. :-P

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The other answers point out that by choosing a "larger" type you permit a broader set of callers to call you. Which is a good enough reason in itself to make this change. However, there are other reasons. I would recommend that you make this change because when I see a method that takes a list or an array, the first thing I think is "what if that method tries to change an item in my list/array?"

You want the contents of a bucket, but you are requiring not just the bucket but also the ability to change its contents. Why would you require that if you're not going to use that ability? When you say "this method cannot take any old sequence; it has to take a *mutable list that is indexed by integers*" I think that you're making that requirement on the caller **because you're going to take advantage of that power**.

If "I'm planning on messing up your data structure" is not what you intend to communicate to the caller of the method then don't communicate that. A method that takes a sequence communicates "The most I'm going to do is read from this sequence in order".

Comment: Switching to `IEnumerable<T>` creates a new issue though: enumerating several times can be problematic now. While that's not the case in this specific example, it can make the choice harder in some other cases.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how enumerating an IEnumerable is problematic compared to enumerating a List.

Comment: @GregD: Because when you enumerate a list you can simply say "give me item one, item two, item three, item four, and now I want item two again". To do the same to an arbitrary sequence you have to start the whole thing over again, which can have significant performance costs. If you need to do that sort of thing, possibly the right thing to do is to either try to cast the IE<T> to IList<T>, or to do a ToList to the IE<T> to get it into list form.

Comment: Ah, I suppose my personal definition for enumeration implies an ordered walkthrough of a list.  If I want item two again, I consider that an operation other than enumeration for which (of course) something that supports random access instead of ordered access is more appropriate.  I read CodeInChaos' comment to suggest that `foreach(T t in myEnum)` is somehow more onerous than `foreach(T t in myList)`.  It would have made more sense if, e.g., a reference to Count vs Count() was made.

Comment: The multiple enumeration problem isn't about fast random access. But for some implementations(That aren't `List<T>` enumerating twice is expensive, because generating each item is expensive. And some enumerables can only be enumerated once.

Comment: "Iterating multiple times": So - if the method needs to traverse the enumeration multiple times _and there is a performance problem_, why not caching the items in the method itself? Something like .ToArray() inside would convert whatever the caller passed in a structure that fits the very local needs, no?

Comment: @BenjaminPodszun: Imagine doing that in multiple methods, and then calling them on large lists. You'd have to create a copy of this large list for each of these methods; if you'd accepted a `List<T>` (or `ICollection<T>` or `T[]`), you wouldn't have to create copies, and your code could be more efficient in both time and memory.

Answer (score 6):

Simply put, accepting an enumerable allows your function to be compatible with a broader scope of input arguments, such as arrays and LINQ queries.

To expound on accepting LINQ queries, one could do:

```
UpdateTermInfo(myTermList.Where(x => somefilter));
```

Additionally, specifying an interface rather than a concrete class allows others to provide their own implementation of that interface. In this way, you are being "subscriptive" rather than "proscriptive." (Yes, I did just make up a word.)

In general (with many exceptions relating to what sort of abilities you want to reserve for potential later modifications), it is a best-practice to implement functions using arguments that are the most general that they can be. This gives maximum flexibility to the consumer of your function.

As a result, if you are dead-set on using a list for this function (perhaps because at some later date you expect you might want to use properties such as `Count` or the index operator), I would strongly urge you to consider using `IList<Term>` instead of `List<Term>` for the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: Can't you use LINQ queries on a list?

Comment: @ThePower David is showing that the **input** can be a LINQ filter... which is **not** a `List<T>`

Comment: @ThePower You definitely can, but the result of such a query would be an enumerable, not a list. You would have to call `ToList` on the result of the query to convert to a list, at a considerable performance penalty.

Comment: Other way round mate, change to IEnumerable means yous could do UpdateTermInfo(Some LINQ query), or anything else that returns IEnumerable.

Comment: @MarcGravell and David - Nice one :)

Comment: So how would you refactor my method with LINQ?

Comment: As ReSharper suggested, simply take IEnumerable.

Answer (score 3):

`List` implements `IEnumerable`, using it would makes things more flexible. If an instance came along where you didn't want to use a `List` and wanted to use a different collection object it would cast from `IEnumerable` with ease.

For instance `IEnumerable` allows you to use `Arrays` and many others as opposed to always using a `List`.

`Inumerable` is simply a collection of items, dissimilar to a `List`, where you can add, remove, sort, use For Each, Count etc.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea behind that refactor is that you make the method more general. You don't say what data structure you want, only what you need from it: that you can iterate through its elements.

So later, when you decide that O(n) search is not good enough for you, you only have to change one line and move along.

Answer (score 0):

If you use List then you are confining yourself to only use a concrete implementation of List where as with IEnumerable you can pass in Arrays, Lists, Collections as they all implement that interface.